# Oracle Cursor output takes long time

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql

I have problem in stored procedure. The stored procedure produces Cursor output. The SQL query which produces the output execute in less than 1 Sec.But procedure takes more than 10 Minutes to execute.Stored procedure doesnot have any other quires.

Comment: Are you measuring the time for the SQL query to return the first row?  Or are you measuring the time for the SQL query to return the last row?  What is the procedure doing other than fetching from the cursor?

Comment: Measuring the time for SQL to return the last row.Output has at the maximum 200 rows. Procedure is doing nothing other than fetching from the cursor

Answer (score 2):

A common reason for such behavior is to confuse the time to return the first (couple of) row(s) with the time needed for all the rows. If you just issue a select in most sql tools you get the first rows as soon as they are available. This does not mean the sql statement is completely processed. Only if you scroll down to the last row the sql processing is finished.